# move WooCommerce checkout login form to after checkout order review

Tags: php, forms, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I want to show the WooCommerce checkout login form just after the checkout order review.

I tried the following:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
```

It was not working. jQuery's code is not working. Login form opened before click the login button.

[image: here is]

I need help to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WooCommerce checkout login form, includes its own `<form>`, it requires to be added outside any existing form, so outside the main checkout form (before or after)...

So what is going to work instead is:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
```

Comment: Now showing on after my payment button. i want to show actually after order review place, here are the snapshot- https://imgur.com/ZnvIQ8n

Comment: You can't have it there (like in your screenshot) as it's inside the checkout form and will not work. `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` is the only available hook after the checkout form.

Comment: i can not have is woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details ?

Comment: No the hook `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details` is inside the checkout main form, see in [checkout/form-checkout.php template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L36)

Comment: line number 36 here i can not?

Comment: Try, if it doesn't work, so that means that you can not…… From line 32 to 64 (included), you can not…